Creating a LAN network behind an untrusted network that blocks router connections
My residence provides Wi-Fi access points as well as Ethernet ports that connect to their network; however, this network 1) requires a captive portal login on Wi-Fi, 2) provides no connection for devices that only support 2.4G, and 3) allows all devices connected to access each other. I run a NAS and some smart home devices, so these are somewhat large issues for me. I'd like to set up a private network for only my devices by plugging an Ethernet cable into my router's WAN port and my residence's Ethernet ports. The desired solution would look something like this:
                                  Residence Network
                                           |
                                           |---------- My Router
                                           |                 |
                                    Public Devices    My Devices

The goal is to completely isolate this second network from all but an outside internet connection, so a double NAT situation is not a problem. Unfortunately, my residence blocks routers from connecting to the network. I have spoken with them and been told my router is allowed under their policies but that they will not unblock routers. This leaves me with two options: make the router look as if it (and all devices connected to it) are only one device, or use my router as a switch and connect all devices directly to their network. The latter is quite undesirable, so I ask: How should I go about making my router look like a normal device while allowing my other devices to connect to it? Additionally, what settings should I enable, disable, or change on my router in order to avoid other problems?

It really depends on how they are detecting your router. Is it by MAC address? If your router is working as a router, it should run "double-NAT" and I don't think they should be able to detect anything from the traffic itself

The main problem is the captive-portal. Is it applied only on the WIFI?

I don't believe it's by MAC address, as enabling MAC spoofing and using my laptop's MAC did not seem to allow the router to connect (the laptop connects just fine). I do have DHCP enabled, but I'm not sure if that should affect anything if I'm using the WAN port. Nothing should try to connect to my router for DHCP assignment, because it wouldn't have been assigned a standard router port by the residence network. I may be misunderstanding how DHCP works, though.

And yes, the captive portal is only applied on Wi-Fi. A wired connection does not require a login.

When you set-up the router, do you set it for static address or DHCP? Can you view logs from it's DHCP client?

Also, just to make sure, do you see DHCP problem on the router or on the devices within the network?

They can detect routers by the TTL (Time to live, i.e. maximum number of hops they can go through before being discarded, to avoid loops) of packets. Usually IP packets start with a TTL of 64, but when they pass through your router they decrease that to 63 (as they should). This can tip your residence to the fact you've got a router. Most commercial routers offer the option to spoof TTL value and always assign 64 to outgoing IP packets.

Apart from this [TTL], your router should be transparent to the network, meaning that you have access to everyone else's computers, captive portals, etc...
Not the other way around because of your router's firewall.

One possibility is to use a SBC similar to a raspberry PI with 2 LAN port.  1. to there system and 1 to your router.  Most SBC use some kind of linux which you can use iptables to setup a DNAT.  Then a DHCP and DNS server and enable ip_route and it should pass traffic.  Since don't know how there detecting routers, I can't be absolutely certain this would work.

How about a VPN connection? If you could connect a router to a VPN of some kind ( one hosted by parents/friends, or maybe even a public one [ again, this should be a pretty-special router ] ) then all the traffic should be encrypted and the building shouldn't be able to see if, and how many, users are connected.
I guess it might be time to build a NAS for DR 
Examples of routers with VPN Client: ( not VPN Server! )
ASUS AX58U https://www.asus.com/networking-iot-servers/wifi-routers/asus-wifi-routers/rt-ax58u/techspec/
LinkSys WRT32X - https://store.linksys.com/support-article?articleNum=270535
Aircove routers - https://www.expressvpn.com/aircove
TP-Link Archer GX90 - https://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/wifi-router/archer-gx90/#specifications

This seems to be the best solution, given that I don’t know how they’re detecting routers. I’ll see what I can do for this, thanks.
